# Assembly loading under TextTransform.exe, Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-assembly, t4

I have a .NET assembly, written in C#, which references the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` and `System.Collections.Immutable` assemblies and contains this function:

```
    public string GetFirstNamespace(string code)
    {
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText (code);
        var root = tree.GetRoot ();
        var @using = root.DescendantNodes ().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax> ();
        var @types = root.DescendantNodes ().OfType<TypeDeclarationSyntax> ();
        var @enums = root.DescendantNodes ().OfType<EnumDeclarationSyntax> ();
        var @namespaces = root.DescendantNodes ().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax> ();
        return @namespaces.First ().GetText ().ToString();
    }
```

I can call this function from a command-line program written in C#:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string code = "using System; namespace Foo { public class Program { public static void Main(string[] args) { Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, World\"); } } }";
        Utilities u = new Utilities();
        string ns = u.GetFirstNamespace(code);
        Console.WriteLine (ns);
    }
```

But if I try to invoke the same method from a T4 template, run using TextTransform.exe, I get into all sorts of bother.  Initially, there are a long list of assemblies that it cannot find:

```
$ /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/TextTransform.exe -P=./bin/Debug T4Template.tt
Processing 'T4Template.tt' failed.
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Runtime.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Collections.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Globalization.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Linq.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Runtime.Extensions.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Threading.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll' could not be found
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `System.Reflection.dll' could not be found
```

Adding one of the installed Mono directories to the assembly search path fixes these, but leads to other problems:

```
$ /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/TextTransform.exe -P=./bin/Debug -P=/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades T4Template.tt
Invalid type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxTree for instance field Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode:_syntaxTree
Processing 'T4Template.tt' failed.
(0,0): ERROR Error running transform: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
  at T4CSTest.Utilities.GetFirstNamespace (System.String code) <0x4047b4e0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GeneratedTextTransformation21eb083a.TransformText () <0x4047afa0 + 0x0009b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x7f7d1d530780 + 0x000a1> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x7f7d1d530780 + 0x000ef> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x7f7d1d368cf0 + 0x0002a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.TextTemplating.CompiledTemplate.Process () <0x4047a520 + 0x0036f> in <filename unknown>:0
```

The same thing works under Visual Studio 2013 on Windows.

I've tried this using the referenced assemblies got from NuGet and also using the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.* assemblies from https://github.com/mono/roslyn, built using Mono 4.2.1 (with a one-line patch to fix a build error).

My basic question here is, how can I get this to work?

A subsidiary question is, why doesn't it find all those System.* assemblies without help?  Shouldn't it find them anyway?  Is this because those Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.* assemblies are built against the PCL?  Adding in the PCL directory to the search path causes an even longer list of problems, mostly with multiply-defined classes (not too unexpected, really).

**Edit** Full demonstration code is available at https://github.com/tomkcook/T4CSTest

Comment: "mono TextTransform.exe T4Template.tt -o foo.txt" works for me... Is this running on Linux? Wondering since you are directly 'executing' an exe. If so, what does your file-type registration look like for `exe`'s? Use `mono` directly to run your CIL assemblies.

Comment: @RobertN: Yes, running on Ubuntu 14.04.  Running with 'mono TextTransform.exe' doesn't help.  When you run with the command line it gives, how is it finding the T4CSTest, System.Collections.Immutable, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp assemblies?

Comment: @RobertN - or for that matter, how does it find TextTransform.exe?  Is that on your system path?

Comment: I should perhaps add that I'm using Mono v4.2.1 from the mono-project.com repository, not the version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: 1) 4.3.0 and 4.2.1 2) I use a custom mono shell driver, but mainly it deals with MONO_PATH. Full pathing works on your example as well 3) Create local copies of the CIL assemblies (exe & dll) and run within that dir first as a test, thus getting the correct references.. 4) Those refs full-paths are also listed in MD/XS when debugging 5) On Linux I mainly deal with Docker-style CIL assem deployments so `everything` is output to the bin dir, i.e. All my references are flagged as local copies so I never use GAC based assem (like MSbuild/xbuild/Monodevelop/Xamarin Studio/etc.. no GAC involved)

Comment: And `mono --help-trace` is your friend :-) tee the output to a file and grep for the load errors, etc...

Comment: Yes, copying TextTransform.exe, Mono.TextTemplating.dll, System.Collections.Immutable.dll, System.Reflection.Metadata.dll, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll to a single folder and then, from that folder, running `mono TextTransform.exe ../T4Template.tt` works.  But running in that same directory but referring to the system installation of TextTransform.exe does not.  Is this some sort of bizarre bug in Mono's assembly loading?

Comment: What do you mean `system installation` of TextTransform.exe ? It is just an exe and a set of dlls... You could add that dir to a MONO_PATH to pick up the assemblies in that dir first, then `mono /path/xxx/xx/TextTransform.exe` would load assemblies from there first...

Comment: You can create a shell script for `TextTransform.exe`, like Mono does for `tool` installations, i.e. ` cat `which xsp4` ` Take a look at that script.

Comment: By "system installation" I mean the one installed with the monodevelop deb package. I don't know why referring to a path in /usr/lib produces a different result to copying the same executable to the current directory - especially since the type it is choking on is loaded from one of the assemblies already in the current directory.

Comment: You would need to run a trace on it and see the difference on where/what is it loading based on your install to pinpoint the issue, I know a lot people run into this issue so I'm `assuming` it is due to how it is ref'd due to it being packaged as an Addin... I normally use it via `mdtool` and `xbuild` and do not call TT engine directly (i.e. via an external cli exe call)..

Comment: Related bug report for anyone else who ends up here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36471